# How to implement E2EE in a chat app ? What are the steps to consider if I want to use diffie hellman key exchange algorithm?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I am currently learning react and node and I have built a realtime chat app using react node with the use of express, axios, socket.io Now the problem is that I want to add E2EE in the chat app. I have researched but I dont know the key sending works like sending key from one place to other and decrypting.